Why $W$ is open in baby Rudin 9.28

9.28 Theorem: Let $f$ be a r $\mathscr{C}'$ -mapping of an open set $E$ $ \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ into $\mathbb{R}^n$, such
that $f(a, b) = 0$ for some point $(a, b) \in E$.
Put $A = f'(a, b)$ and assume that $A_x$ is invertible.
Then there exist open sets $U\subset \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$ and $W \subset \mathbb{R}^m$, with $(a, b) \in U$ and
$b \in W$, having the following property:
$$(x,y ) \in U\ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ f(x,y)=0. \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
 (56)$$
If this $x$ is defined to be $g(y)$, then $g$ is a $\mathscr{C}'$ -mapping of $W$ into $\mathbb{R}^n$, $g(b) = a$,

In the Proof it was  written If $V$
is open in $R^{n+m}$
, and $W=\{y:(0,y)∈V\}$
, Then $W$ is open
I don't know why $W$ is an open set or even why $W$ is an infinite set (every finite set can't be open).




It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

@JoséCarlosSantos It is a lot to write, It will take me some time to finish

@Mathematicsenjoyer: You do not need to write the whole thing. The problem you are asking can be simply phrased as "If $V$ is open in $\mathbb R^{n+m}$, and $W = {y: (0,y)\in V}$, why is $W$ open?"

@AlexOrtiz Thabks for the suggestion

$\vec y\in W$$\implies$ $(\vec 0,\vec y)\in V$ $\implies$ exists $r>0$ s.t. if $d((\vec z, \vec w),(\vec 0,\vec y))<r$, then $(\vec z, \vec w)\in W$. Can you then conclude the existence of $r'>0$ s.t. $d(\vec y,\vec w)<r$ implies $(0,\vec w)\in V$ ($\implies \vec w\in W$)? (Take $\vec z=0$ in above.)

Take $\mathbf y\in W$. Then, $(\mathbf 0, \mathbf y)\in V$. Since $V$ is open, find $\varepsilon>0$ such that
$$\mathrm{B}_\varepsilon(\mathbf0,\mathbf y)\subset V$$
Then, you claim $\mathrm{B}_\varepsilon(\mathbf y)\subset W$. Take $z\in\mathrm{B}_\varepsilon(\mathbf y)$, then
$$\left\|(\mathbf0,\mathbf z)-(\mathbf0,\mathbf y)\right\|=\left\|\mathbf z-\mathbf y\right\|<\varepsilon$$
and so $(\mathbf 0,\mathbf z)\in V$ so $\mathbf z\in W$. So, we are done.
Hope this helps. :)

@BrianMoehring: My bad, I don't know what I was thinking. I removed it.
